# Wait for at least 5 minutes for element to appear

Tags: c#, selenium

I tried a lot of solutions in the internet but everyone of them didn't work on al cases, I just want to wait until the element appear in the web page, I'm using selenium for c#
two of the things that I tried, and the two of them throw an exception once in a while, I just don't want to get an exception, I want my automation to wait for at least 5 minutes for the web page to load.

```
public class WaitForElement
    {
        public void WaitFE(string Xpath,IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver,    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120));
            wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath)).Displayed);
            //IWebElement category = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            //{
            //    return d.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath));
            //});

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you waiting for after page load?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be to use Explicit wait until the element you're finding meets your desired conditions:

-wait for the element to exist:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("")));
```

-wait for element to be visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("")));
```

-wait for element to be clickable

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("")));
```

Or anything else you need.
And by settings the `TimeSpan` here `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));` it will wait by default 5 minutes (the max time for the expected condition to be true).

Another thing that you could do, would be to use an Implicit wait as a default maximum loading time for all pages:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that i solved my problem, this wait function waits approximately 2 minutes for the element to appear,
can anyone tell me if what I did is good

```
public class WaitForElement
    {
        public int count = 0;
        public void WaitFE(string Xpath,IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!(count < 10 && (webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath)).Displayed)))
                {
                    count = 0;
                    return;
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                count++;
                WaitFE(Xpath, webDriver);
            }

        }
```