# Is there an approach for waiting for a process to complete for 5 minutes

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd

I am automating using selenium Java, and an action called 'preview' will submit an extract(financial data) process and it will enter a stage called 'previewing'. It normally takes 2-5 minutes of time to complete the 'previewing' process and the stage changes to 'draft'.

Explicit wait as per this answer is one method. [Wait for 5 min for an element to appear or a process to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390541/wait-for-at-least-5-minutes-for-element-to-appear)

**Is there a better approach ? Does Serenity offer anything over and above Selenium ?**

Comment: What are the values 'previewing' and 'draft'? Some WebElement's attribute? Add the html source code, your attepmt and it's failure (exception if any).

Comment: 'previewing' and 'draft' are the status of the extract, I have kicked off which is the process which I referred. The status changes from 'previewing' to 'draft' and it is on a web page, whose weblocator I can have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Explicit wait for 1 min and use it within a while loop. For e.g.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By(Identifier for DRAFT Status));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
while (element == null) {
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By(Identifier for DRAFT Status)); 
}
```

Comment: Let me try and see. I will get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

In classic Serenity Page Objects:

```
withTimeoutOf(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).waitFor(DRAFT_STATUS_ELEMENT);
```

In Screenplay:

```
WaitUntil.the(DRAFT_STATUS_ELEMENT, isVisible()).forNoMoreThan(300).seconds())
```